# Newtonsoft Json deserializer not releasing memory

Tags: c#, memory, json.net

I'm using a `StreamReader` with `JsonTextReader` to deserialize a large JSON file containing tens of thousands of small objects, and its consuming *way* more memory than I think is reasonable (and running out). I'm using what I understand is the recommended pattern for reading large files.

Code simplified for expository purposes:

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
{
    JToken token;
    while (reader.Read() && reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)
    {
        token = JToken.Load(reader);
        RawResult result = token.ToObject<RawResult>();
        results.Add(result);
    }
}
```

The VS2015 memory profiler is telling me that most of the memory is being consumed by `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue` objects, which is bizarre because once the current token has been converted `ToObject()` there is no reason (as far as I am concerned) why it shouldn't just be discarded.

I'm assuming that the Newtonsoft library is retaining all of the JSON parsed so far in memory. I don't need it to do this and I think if I could prevent this my memory problems would go away.

What can be done?

Comment: hard to comment when we don't know what "results" is defined as.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like you need to be using JTokens as an intermediary; you could just deserialize directly to your `RawResult` class inside your loop.

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    while (reader.Read() && reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)
    {
        RawResult result = serializer.Deserialize<RawResult>(reader);
        results.Add(result);
    }
}
```

Also note that by adding your result items to a list, you are keeping them all in memory.  If you can process them one at a time and write each result individually to your output (file, database, network stream, etc.) you can save memory that way also.

```
        RawResult result = serializer.Deserialize<RawResult>(reader);
        ProcessResult(result);  // process result now instead of adding to a list
```

Comment: You are quite right that I don't need to use `JToken`s and removing this in favour of `JsonSerializer` simplifies the code nicely. But I'm still running out of memory at the same point and for the same reason.

Comment: OK, this is *very* weird. If I discard each `RawResult` as it is created, there is no build-up of `JToken` objects. Does Json.Net somehow inject a 'hidden' reference from a deserialized object back to the JSON node it was created from?

Comment: Does your `RawResult` class contain any properties that are defined as `object` that are non-null in the JSON?  If so, they will contain JTokens.

Comment: I made a mistake: It is `JValue` objects that are accumulating, not `JToken` objects. I still can't explain it though.

Comment: Also note that `JValue` is a subclass of `JToken`.

Comment: OK, I've found it (I think). One of the fields inside `RawResult` is a plain `object`. It seems that this is remaining as type `JToken`, which references its parent in the JSON tree hence preventing any garbage collection. Thanks for your help. I think the mystery is solved.

Comment: If you don't need that property for processing, you should be able to remove it from the class without causing any errors in deserialization.  Json.Net will just skip over it.

Comment: Actually I do need it; and that particular property can be either a number or a string (which is why it is declared as `object`). I'll find some other way to represent it.

Comment: When you found out that the `object` was remaining as type `JToken` what did you do to release the memory?  I'm facing the same problem.  My web app is retaining a bunch of memory and it looks like they are also JTokens.  I found that my property was also an object.  We tried to set the parent class object to null before disposing but it doesn't seem to work.